# Optaplanner - Different start and stop location for vehicle (time windowed vrp)

Tags: optaplanner

How can I set **different start and stop locations for the vehicles**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the java class `Vehicle` from having a `Depot` to having a starting `Location` and an ending `Location`. Then adjust the `scoreRules.drl` accordingly.

Comment: I know Milenko's question was a bit terse, but perhaps you could help me? I've created additional properties and have been playing around with the rules but I've not got it right yet.

What I've tried is

`rule "distanceFromFirstCustomerToStart"
    when
        $customer : Customer(previousStandstill == null)
    then
        Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle) $customer.getVehicle();
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $customer.getDistanceToStart(vehicle));
end`

But this isn't working, maybe I'm not understanding the how to construct the rule?